# Dirichlet problem on electric circuit with many entries

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Let us consider an electric circuit consisting only of resistors. Let us also distinguish some set of nodes $\partial$ which we will call the boundary of this circuit. Then we define the matrix of effective resistances:

$$R_{ij} = \mbox{effective resistance between nodes i and j},$$

for $i, j \in \partial$. I have two questions:

1) Suppose that we attach some potentials to the boundary: to the node $i$ we attach potential $\phi_i$. Is it possible to determine the current flow through all the boundary nodes knowing only the matrix of resistances?

2) If 1) is true how can we calculate the boundary current?

Comment: How can you calculate the *"current flowing through the boundary"*, when at each node in the circuit the sum of all the currents is zero? What you mean by current through the boundary? You can calculate the currents through the resistors.

Comment: When I attach a potential to the boundary I have to use some cables (which are not the part of my circuit). By a boundary current in a node I mean the current flowing to this node from a power supply.

Comment: This is a mathematical problem.

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics we have boundary value problems or initial value problems or a mix. For the first you need steady state and specification of the values on All the boundary points. Your case belong to this I guess. So the answer is no, you have to know all the boundary points. For initial values problems and this you need if you have storage elements like capacitors and inductors or inertia, then you need to specify the initial values inside and on the boundary before you can continue. Having said this, there is also the superposition principle for linear problems, where you can add many solutions each one is made up of one point value on the boundary with the rest grounded and with the inside element values all known.

Comment: If I knew the shape of whole circuit then my problem is very simple - I need only to solve the discrete Laplace equation with some boundary condition. This is well known problem. 

What do You mean by "you have to know all the boundary points"?